# How to get the file size of a video using pytube?

Tags: pytube

Heyoo! In this code, I am trying to download youtube videos and show a bit of information about them, such as the title, rating, views, etc. I am also trying to get the file size of it, however, I am having a bit of difficulty doing so. I want to find the size of the video using only the URL. I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong with the Stream object. Anyways, here is my code:

```
from pytube import YouTube, Stream
import time

link = input("Youtube Link: ")
video = YouTube(link)


print(f"""
Title: {video.title}
Owner: {video.channel_id}
Length: {video.length}
Date Published: {video.publish_date}
Rating: {video.rating}
Views: {video.views}
File Size: {video.filesize}
""")

video_resolution = video.streams.get_highest_resolution()
time.sleep(1)
print("Donwloading... ")
video_resolution.download('YoutubeVideoDownloader/DonwloadedVideo')
print("Download complete!")
```

It would be great if you guys could let me know what I am doing wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

you need to specify the quality of the video for example the highest resolution video size will be

```py
video.streams.get_highest_resolution().filesize
```

Answer (score 0):

from pytube  import YouTube

Link = ""

yt = YouTube (Link)

yt.streams.get_by_itag(17).filesize